# Iptables rule to allow only one port and block others

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall, netstat

We have two apps running (on top of linux) and both communicates through port 42605. I wanted to quickly verify if this is the only port that's been used for communication between them. I tried below rule, but it doesn't seems to work. So, just wanted to get this clarified, if I am doing it wrong.

Following is the sequence of commands i ran

```
iptables -I INPUT -j REJECT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 42605 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 42605 -j ACCEPT
```

So, this will get added in reverse order since I am inserting it.

I wanted to allow incoming and outgoing communications from and to 42605. Does the above rule looks good or am I doing it wrong?

Another question, would this be the right way to test, or maybe I should use "netstat" command to see which port has connection established with the other ip?

Comment: Since you're just doing research, instead of doing a `-j REJECT` you should do a `-j LOG`. This is because `REJECT` will drop the packet and send back an ICMP `destination unreachable` packet to the affected client. `LOG` will just send the packet information to syslog (on most systems it ends up in `/var/log/messages`) then the packet is processed normally. So `REJECT` will likely break the application (at least temporarily) and you're at the mercy of what THAT causes the app to do, versus just logging the information and doing a `tail -f` on `/var/log/messages`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can make INPUT policy drop to block everything and allow specific ports only

```
# allow established sessions to receive traffic
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# allow your application port
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 42605 -j ACCEPT
# allow SSH 
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
# Allow Ping
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# allow localhost 
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
# block everything else 
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

> Another question, would this be the right way to test, or maybe I
>   should use "netstat" command to see which port has connection
>   established with the other ip?

Yes, you can check `netstat -antop | grep app_port` and you can also use strace :

```
strace -f -e trace=network -s 10000 PROCESS ARGUMENTS
```

To monitor an existing process with a known pid:

```
strace -p $( pgrep application_name) -f -e trace=network -s 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to allow ping:

```
iptables -A  INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8/0 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8/0 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```